# How to set a timeout so that an await takes at least a certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For visual reasons, I need to show a certain component for at least 1000ms. The flag for the component is toggled before an async call is made and it's turned back off after the call finishes.

I need the component to show for 1 second if the async call is shorter than that, and for the time the async call requires if that is longer than 1 second.

That is, I have two cases.

1.) time needed by async <= 1s: show the component for 1s
2.) time needed by async > 1s: show the component for the time needed by the async call. And *not that time + 1s*

How would you approach this? I played around with setting timeouts, but in that case that times seem to add up.

Answer (score 0):

For example, to wait for 1 second in an `async` function:

```
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
```

You could also extract this into a more convenient utility:

```
function wait(seconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000))
}

await wait(1)
```

Comment: That doesn't ensure that it waits for the operation if the operation takes more than a second.

Comment: Then just run both with `Promise.all`